# How to infer shader type with "shaderc_glsl_infer_from_source"?

Tags: glsl, shader, vulkan, shaderc

I am using shaderc for compiling my shaders. In order to do so, I have to specify the type of shader (`shaderc_shader_kind`). One of the available types is `shaderc_glsl_infer_from_source`. The in-code comments say that this type "deduce the shader kind from `#pragma` annotation in the source code, and compiler will emit error if `#pragma` annotation is not found".

I have tried putting `#pragma vertex_shader` or `#pragma shaderc_vertex_shader` like in the code below, but the program stops working anyway.

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#pragma shaderc_fragment_shader

// The rest of the shader goes here
```

I get the following error:

```
Shader module compilation failed -
Validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID_Undefined ] Object 0: handle = 0x1fa16e5fd90, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x79de34d4 | vkCreateShaderModule: parameter pCreateInfo->codeSize / 4 must be greater than 0.
Validation layer: Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-Shader-InconsistentSpirv ] Object 0: handle = 0x1fa16e5fd90, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x6bbb14 | SPIR-V module not valid: Invalid SPIR-V magic number.
Failed to create shader module!
```

However, everything works fine when, instead of using `shaderc_glsl_infer_from_source`, I specify the type of shader manually (`shaderc_vertex_shader` or `shaderc_fragment_shader`) in my Vulkan code. Unfortunately, this is not convenient in my case.

What am I doing wrong? Is the `#pragma` directive correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging around in their source code and stumbling into the related [test code](https://github.com/google/shaderc/blob/4dc596ddc2702092c670e828745dc3e0338d83c1/libshaderc/src/common_shaders_for_test.h#L133), the pragmas seem to be `#pragma shader_stage(something)`:

```
// Vertex only shader with #pragma annotation.
const char kVertexOnlyShaderWithPragma[] =
    "#version 310 es\n"
    "#pragma shader_stage(vertex)\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(1.);\n"
    "}";

// Fragment only shader with #pragma annotation.
const char kFragmentOnlyShaderWithPragma[] =
    "#version 310 es\n"
    "#pragma shader_stage(fragment)\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "    gl_FragDepth = 10.;\n"
    "}";
```

and a lot more, `tesscontrol`, `tesseval`, `geometry`, `compute`, `mesh`, `task`.